# What does tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn argument mean?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

everyone!
I'm new on Tensorflow. At [Getting Started with TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#tensorflow_core_tutorial), I got the `tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x": x_train}, y_train, 4, num_epochs=1000)` source. I wonder what does `batch_size` and `num_epochs` mean? I tried to change the tutorial value and get no effect for me.

I searched on [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/s/results/?q=tf.contrib.learn.io&p=%2F) and [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/numpy_io.py) but fail.

Please let me know what's this or where could i search about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that we split the whole training set of data to the small chunks (batches). So **batch_size** sets the size of this chunk. And **num_epochs** describes the chunks quantity. 
You could find the description in the comments of the [Getting Started with TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started#tensorflow_core_tutorial):

```
# We have to tell the function how many batches
# of data (num_epochs) we want and how big each batch should be.
```

Comment: Therefore what does `steps` mean? I think that `num_epochs` be the number of the training step. Is that right?

Comment: No. They are related, but they are not the same things. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340311/what-is-the-difference-between-steps-and-epochs and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319709/tensorflow-nr-of-epochs-vs-nr-of-training-steps